# How can I get my TripIt calendar to show up on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, tripit, icalendar

I want to see my upcoming TripIt travel plans on my Google Calendar.  I thought I would just be able to subscribe to my TripIt ical feed from GCal, but it doesn't seem to work.

I got my ical feed from TripIt; it looks something like this:

```
webcal://www.tripit.com/feed/ical/private/**obscured private identifier**/tripit.ics
```

I then tried pasting that link into the 'Add By URL' option to add an external calendar to my Google Calendar.  No error is displayed, but no events appear on my calendar either.

I then tried changing `webcal://` in the link to my TripIt feed to `http://` but I got the same results.

Has anyone else successfully done this?  Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official directions on how to add it to Google Calendar](http://www.tripit.com/uhp/calendarInfo#google), it shows a calendar URL in a format that is different than the one you supplied: `http://www.tripit.com/calendar/ical/...`

Your URL has `feed` and `private` in it. It might be due to privacy concerns and only your public events can be displayed.

You could try seeing if there are other iCal URLs for your calendar:
I don't have an account so I can't try it, but this url should take you to where the iCal feed is: https://www.tripit.com/account/login?redirect_url=uhp%2FcalendarInfo

Comment: It seems that Google has changed their interface, so although the screenshots in that tutorial don't quite match up to what I was doing, I'm pretty certain that I was following the same steps.

Comment: Or, maybe I'm just crazy.  I tried again, and it worked (though I can't for the life of me tell you what I did differently this time).

Answer (score 4):

Google takes a surprising long time to refresh the other calendars... usually "6-24 hours" which, in my experience, is almost enough to make their iCal support nearly worthless.

See this [related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6313/how-often-does-google-calendar-update-its-other-calendar-feeds).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for a long time and [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/how-can-i-force-google-calendar-to-sync-update-my-tripit-ical-feed?lq=1) had the answer.

Remove the "www." from the calendar feed URL.

Change

```
https://www.tripit.com/feed/ical/private/XXX...XXX/tripit.ics
```

into

```
https://tripit.com/feed/ical/private/XXX...XXX/tripit.ics
```

Comment: And if the "www." part isn't there, but the calendar still won't update? See here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82239/9949

Answer (score 0):

Besides importing your iCal URL into google calendar,  you'll also have to make sure that you are a traveler on the trip. Make sure you check the following check box if you want your trip to show up in Google calendar.

Options > Edit > I'm a traveler on this trip.