# How often is the Trello webcal page updated?

Tags: trello, google-calendar

I am wondering how often the Trello webcal page is updated. I would like to have my Trello due dates appear in my Google Calendar, but I need to ensure that the dates are being propagated to Google Calendar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Calendar updates "every few hours." Unfortunately, it's not a configurable setting. See [How often does Google Calendar update its "Other Calendar" feeds?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6313/how-often-does-google-calendar-update-its-other-calendar-feeds)

The Trello iCalendar feed requests that clients refresh the feed hourly, but they have no obligation to do so (and, indeed, Google Calendar ignores that request). You can see the last time the feed was updated in each event's description under "Feed Last Updated."(Source: I'm the Trello dev who wrote the iCalendar feed)

Comment: Interesting. I would not have thought that it was Google that was causing the delayed updating. This is not a major concern to me luckily, but it is good to know so that I am not sitting there wondering why a due date may not have appeared. My idea is to use Trello to organize homework for my upcoming school year, and adding due dates and using the ical feed in Google Calendar really allows me to stay on top of things!