# How can I force Google Calendar to sync/update my Tripit iCal feed?

Tags: google-calendar, tripit

I have had my TripIt feed registered in my Google Calendar for several years, mostly without issue.  However, sometimes, entries that a clearly and accurately registered in TripIt just don't show up in Google Calendar.

I currently have a trip that has both hotel and air reservations in TripIt; it's been in there for weeks, and the trip starts tomorrow, but it still hasn't shown up in Google Calendar.  Oddly, I have past trips, in the last few weeks that are correctly in Google Calendar.  And I have future trips that are correctly in Google Calendar.  But this one just isn't.

I've manually examined the XML and iCal feeds, and the trip is present.  Google Calendar just isn't respecting/reflecting it.

Is there any way to "force" a Google Calendar sync?  I've tried adding/removing the feed, to no avail...

Comment: I saw that question, but it hasn't helped me solve the actual problem, unfortunately.  This trip has been untouched in TripIt for 2 weeks, but still hasn't shown up.

Comment: it could also be that the feed is not compatible with Google Calendar's syntax (and yes I have seen feeds where some ical syntax which was totally valid by online validators did not have all events instances displayed in Google Calendar)

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, as I found a solution.  Actually, I contacted TripIt support, and after a few roundtrips, they offered a suggestion that finally worked...

> Remove the "www." from the calendar feed URL.

Yep.  That's it.  Problem solved.  I can go catch my flight now.  Thanks.

Comment: That is amazing and completely ridiculous. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The more complete answer is to **toggle** the `www.` part of the TripIt feed URL when you re-add it.

I recently had this problem. My work GCalendar was using tripit.com and my personal GCalendar was using www.tripit.com. No updates on either one, several hours after the TripIt feed was updated.

To force them both to refresh, I re-added the TripIt feed to the work calendar *with* the `www.` and then re-added the TripIt feed to the personal calendar *without* the `www.` part.

Both refreshed almost immediately. To make sure this works again, next time I need it, I "hid" the non-refreshed versions of the feeds which will hopefully make google forget them.

<sub>I suspect they have some optimization where they stop refreshing calendars that aren't recently used. Haven't traveled in awhile? Yeah, you'll need this. Google is great with algorithms but sadly out of touch with what people really need.</sub>