# How can I get a Confluence calendar's events to show up in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar, feeds

I followed [these instructions in Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/teamcal/subscribe-to-team-calendars-from-google-calendar-273285887.html) and got a calendar url of

```
https://confluence.[enterprise domain redacted]/rest/calendar-services/1.0/calendar/export/subcalendar/[calendar ID redacted].ics?os_authType=basic&isSubscribe=true
```

Note that when I follow that URL in a browser, I get a .ics file that downloads, and when I open it in Mac OS Calendar app, it imports the events as expected. That URL requires authentication though - if I visit it from an Incognito window, it prompts for a login.

I copied that URL, and in Google Calendar, I went to "Add Other Calendars" > "From URL", and pasted in that URL. None of this Confluence calendar's events show up in Google Calendar, and there is no prompt in Google Calendar to enter a username or password. The added calendar is set to be shown in Google Calendar (the checkbox next to it in the list is checked).

I referenced this similar question: [How can I get my TripIt calendar to show up on Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/how-can-i-get-my-tripit-calendar-to-show-up-on-google-calendar) and saw that it said Google Calendar can take up to 24 hours to refresh events from an external calendar, but I first added this calendar over a week ago, and I am still seeing no events in Google Calendar. None of the other suggestions resolved my problem.

Comment: It may be because of access permissions. Does it require a user to be logged in? Does the URL of the calendar load from a private chrome/firefox tab?

Comment: @V13 Good catch. It does require the user to be logged in. I updated the question with details on that. The thing is, there's no prompt or field for a username and password in Google Calendar when adding the URL there.

Comment: you may have the know issue #1 from here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/teamcal/subscribe-to-team-calendars-from-google-calendar-273285887.html